# how to send a wizard form to rest controller using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've a bunch of sections in a div each section contains same form fields as

```
<div id="wizard_form">
    <section id="1">

        <input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" required />

        <input type="text" name="user_email" id="user_email" required />

        <input type="password" name="user_password" id="user_name" required />

        <input type="password" name="user_pass_repeat" id="user_pass_repeat" required />

        <select id="user_gender" name="user_gender" required>
            <option value="">Select Gender</option>
            <option value="Male">Male</option>
            <option value="Female">Female</option>                                       
        </select>

    </section>
    <section id="2">

        <input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" required />

        <input type="text" name="user_email" id="user_email" required />

        <input type="password" name="user_password" id="user_name" required />

        <input type="password" name="user_pass_repeat" id="user_pass_repeat" required />

        <select id="user_gender" name="user_gender" required>
            <option value="">Select Gender</option>
            <option value="Male">Male</option>
            <option value="Female">Female</option>                                       
        </select>

    </section>
    <section id="3">

        <input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" required />

        <input type="text" name="user_email" id="user_email" required />

        <input type="password" name="user_password" id="user_name" required />

        <input type="password" name="user_pass_repeat" id="user_pass_repeat" required />

        <select id="user_gender" name="user_gender" required>
            <option value="">Select Gender</option>
            <option value="Male">Male</option>
            <option value="Female">Female</option>                                       
        </select>

    </section>                         

</div>
```

now on screen there appears one section with Next and previous buttons to go back and forth to the desired sections on that change event I'm sending data from single section input fields using ajax as

```
onChanging: function(i, e, a) {

    var user_name = $("#wizard_form :input[id='user_name']").val();
    var user_email = $("#wizard_form :input[id='user_email']").val();
    var user_password = $("#wizard_form :input[id='user_password']").val();
    var user_gender = $("#wizard_for" ).find("select[name='user_gender']").val();
    var ajaxUrl = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/submit-ajax;

    /**
     * Ajax Logic 
     * */
    $.ajax({
        contentType : 'application/json',
        crossDomain: true,
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxUrl,
        dataType : 'json',
        data : JSON.stringify({ 
            'userName' : user_name,
            'userEmail' : user_email,
            'userPassword' : user_password,
            'userGender' : user_gender
        })
    })
}
```

There need to be a way of collecting data from all sections and and at last section finish button should submit all the data to the RestController.

Comment: IDs should unique for a start

Comment: My _mistake_ there are sections with different _IDs_ I did not mentioned those. Eidted

Comment: No, I mean ALL IDs - `var user_name = $("#wizard_form :input[id='user_name']").val();` you are collecting from ID `user_name` so which one should it choose?

Comment: that is the problem I'm stuck in, do not have any idea, please can you do a favor and give a solution!

Comment: There's no way to differentiate them other than by number (first, second etc) which I would strongly advise against - this is simply invalid code and to try make it work is not a good use of your time, or anyone elses